# getThreads() does not read all emails in thread

Tags: javascript

I have 4 emails in the Gmail label "MyLabel". 
- 1st thread has 43 email messages
- 2nd thread has 1 email message
- 3rd thread has 2 email messages
- 4th thread has 1 email message

When I use the following code, it appears that I only have 4 emails because my output (which parses correctly) only reads the last email message in each thread instead of all threads. I would like to have 47 rows of output instead of only 4 rows.

```
  var start = 0;
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    var content = messages[0].getPlainBody();
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try looping through `messages`:inside the `threads` loop. `messages` is an array, so you want `messages[0].getPlainBody()` then `messages[1].getPlainBody()`, etc up to `messages.length - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, John!! Having a messages.length-1 loop inside my threads loop was the solution. I used the following and got 49 rows instead of 4. So I think it worked!!

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

```
for (var j = 0; j <messages.length-1; j++) {

var content = messages[j].getPlainBody();
```

Comment: now a related question, please. Once I ran this code and parsed the 50 messages to Google Sheet, how do I only read new messages and append the new parsing to the same sheet?